# In perl, how to split a string in this desired way?

Tags: perl, split, chomp

I have a string `str a\tb\tc\td\te`

I want the 1st field value `a` to go in a variable, then 2nd field value `b` to go in other variable, then both `c\td` to go in 3rd variable and last field value `e` to go in one variable.

If I do

```
my ($a,$b,$c,$d) = split(/\t/,$_,4);
```

`$c` will acquire only `c` and `$d` will acquire `d\te`

I can do:

```
my ($a,$b,$c) = split(/\t/,$_,3);
```

Then `c` will get `c\td\te`
and I can somehow (How?) get rid of last value and get it in `$d`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` is good when you're keeping the order.  If you're breaking the ordering like this you have a bit of a problem.  You have two choices:

1. split according to `\t` and then join the ones you want.
2. be explicit.

an example of the first choice is:

```
my ($a,$b,$c1, $c2, $d) = split /\t/, $_;
my $c = "$c1\t$c2";
```

an example of the second choice is:

```
my ($a, $b, $c, $d) = (/(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?\t.*?)\t(.*?)/;
```

each set of parentheses captures what you want exactly.  Using the non-greedy modifier (`?`) after the `*` ensures that the parentheses won't capture `\t`.

---

**Edit:** if the intent is to have an arbitrary number of variables, you're best off using an array:

```
my @x = split /\t/, $_;

my $a = $x[0];
my $b = $x[1];
my $c = join "\t", @x[2..($#x-1)];
my $d = $x[-1];
```

Comment: +1 for splitting and joining, most simple and readable solution.

Comment: Actually, my real requirement was that, last but one variable should get everything except the last value (and except for first initial 2 values). So there can be more than 2 values. Command should be able to recognize that.

Comment: ok it is working if I swap he order of arguments in join..thanks.

Comment: timtowtdi: `my $a = shift @x; my $b = shift @x; my $d = pop @x; $c = join "\t", @x;` note that this is only useful if this is the only use of `@x` the 0, 1 and -1 elements are removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with a negative look-ahead assertion, e.g.:

```
my @fields = split /\t(?!d)/, $string;
```

Comment: this would group the 4th and 5th together. the OP wants to group the 3rd and 4th, and leave the 5th on its own.

Comment: actually, no.  it's possible that I read it wrong.  Can you post an example?